# How to convert unicode font to ansi

Tags: unicode, fonts, adobe, ansi

I am trying to use bengali writing product [AVRO](http://www.omicronlab.com/) but since it uses UNICODE by default so working with ADOBE products like photoshop, pagemaker, etc. are not working at all. When i change the mode to ANSI then AVRO works but i also have to change the font to ANSI coded font(unicoded fonts dont work). Now it will be very kind if someone find any one of them -

**1) Collection of Bengali ANSI coded fonts.**

```
or
```

**2) Method to convert these UNICODE fonts to ANSI fonts(if its possible, I dont know actually)**

```
or
```

**3) A workaround to use them on Adobe products and still using the unicoded fonts.**

Comment: This is an extraordinary bad idea.  Ask at superuser.com how to whack these Adobe programs into the 21st century.

Comment: Ok i have done that but its so dissapointing that after long 10 years some awesome bengali writing software came out after `SATYAJIT` but still the cant use it due to this minor problem. Is there no way to convert unicode fonts to convert to ANSI ? I am starting to loose my faith.

Comment: AVRO can be used to type in ANSI too. Please install the latest version and click the settings. You will see a bunch of options including Unicode to ANSI converter and also type in ANSI. Double confirm your selection and start working as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous software like Indica, Ramdhenu, Easy DTP etc. to type in Pagemaker, Photoshop, coreldraw etc. I use and prefer Indica.